# ¿Por qué se ejecuta dos veces subscribe en angular?

Tags: angular, ionic, rxjs

Estoy trabajando con ngx socket io, cada vez que mi socket se conecte al servidor, reviso algunos datos que tengo en LocalStorage y los envío para almacenarlos en mi Base de datos principal.

Estoy usando namespace de socket io porque quiero mantener mi logica separada, así que hago lo siguiente.

Creo un servicio por cada namespace que voy a manejar

Dejare el link del repo por si necesitan mas detalles
https://dev.azure.com/raulandrade0511/_git/Testing%20Socket

```
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//Services
import { EmployeeService } from '../services/employee.service';
import { OfflineService } from '../services/offline.service';

//Interfaces
import { HttpResponse } from '../interfaces/http-response.interface';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TestSocketOne extends Socket {  //Heredo de Socket para cada clase que use un namespace
  token: string;

  constructor(
    private employeeService: EmployeeService,
    private offlineService: OfflineService
  ) {
    super({ url: 'http://localhost:4000/testSocketOne', options: {} }); //Le indico la url con el manespace a connectarse

    this.initSocket();
  }

  async initSocket() {
    this.employeeService.token.subscribe((res) => { // estoý usando un middleware paraprotejer mi conexión
      this.token = res; //Obtengo mi token del local Storage
      this.ioSocket['auth'] = { token: this.token }; // Se lo asigno a mi Socket
      this.connect(); // Ejecuto la conexion
      this.onConnection(); //Metodo que detecta cada vez que se conecta al Socket
      this.receivedData();
    });
  }

  onConnection() {
    console.log('This method must be called once');
    this.fromEvent('connect').subscribe((message) => {
      console.log('This event must be called once by connection');
      this.sendData(); // Cada vez que se conecta al socket envío algunos datos de mi local Storage
    });
  }

  async sendData() {
    const data = await this.offlineService.storedData();
    if (data != null) {
      this.emit('sending-data', data); //Envío los datos en un evento de Socket
      console.log('mandando dato al socket'); // Está linea siempre se imprime 2 veces
    }
  }

  async receivedData() { //Al recibir los datos en el back, respondo con otro evento al front
    this.fromEvent<HttpResponse>('received-data').subscribe(async (res) => { // este es el evento que confirma el envío de datos
      const { message } = res.data;
      console.log('respuesta del back es ', message);
     /**
      * Aqui limpiaria mi local storage para no doplicar
      * registros en mi base de datos
      * pero al envíar 2 veces los datos antes de poder recibir una respuesta
      * estoy duplicando mis registros en la base datos,
      * y al intentar registrar la segunda vez, obtengo un error con valores unique
      */
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: si esta siendo desencadenado con un evento a lo mejor el evento se esta ejecutando 2 veces ...

Answer (score 0):

socket io transmite el mensaje a través de toda la aplicación para que tú lo recibas, para evitar repeticiones deberías enviar los datos con el sender id.

(Del lado del server)

```
socket.emit('enviar:mensaje', {mensaje: msg, sender_id: 'TU ID DE USUARIO' });
```

Siempre que recibas un evento/mensaje, debes verificar la identificación del remitente y hacerlo coincidir con tu propia identificación, si ambas identificaciones son iguales, guardas en base de datos.

```
socket.on('enviar:mensaje', function (datos) { if(data.sender_id === 'TU ID DE USUARIO'){ this.sendData(); };
```